# Strftime does not work - %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S

Tags: python, strftime

Okay so here's the example

```
%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f
2022/12/05 00:00:04.530418100
```

I have tried this as a reference https://strftime.org to create one.

I want to get whole 9 digits after 04. I guess %f only gets me 6 digits.
How do I fetch whole 9 digits

Comment: `%S` would just be `04`, but you have `04.530418100`.

Comment: You need to use `%f` to get microseconds. That will be 6 digits after the decimalm, I don't think there's a way to get any more precision.

Comment: But still it get's only 6 digits after decimal, I think I want the whole 9 digits; which is nano seconds I suppose.